# Whats happenning with my logic levels?

Tags: communication, level-shifting, logic-level

I'm using a 3.3 MCU and a 5v logic RS-485 IC. I'm trying to send out some data to another controller. I don't have a logic level shifter as of now. So I decided to use resistor divider, to get it to a safe limit of 3V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVHwyZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The output I'm getting is confusing. When I don't connect the 3V RX data out to the MCU RX Pin, the logic levels are working fine.
[image]

But when I connect this RX out pin to the RX pin of the MCU then the voltage level seems to float.

[image]

I checked the ground levels and it was just the same. Then I thought it could be some impedance issue, but nowhere it explicitly states the impedance of the UART input pin.

What's wrong here?
If it helps, I'm using TI's C2000 series controller.

Comment: It looks as though you are missing a ground connection between the 5 V and 3.3 V circuits. Double-check. Where is your scope ground? (Mark it in on your schematic along with the 3.3 V GND.

Comment: Isn't that an error in the schematic? I'd expect the 5V to be TX, right?

Comment: Maybe you have an internal pull-up enabled. The internal pullups are around 150uA within their compliance range, and that's pretty much the waveform I'd expect if it was enabled.

Comment: @transistor I added scope ground to the schematic. All grounds are common.

Comment: @transistor The only change I did between the two scope captures is adding / removing the RX mcu pin that connects to the RX data OUT from RS485 IC

Comment: @Wojciech I'm not getting what you are saying.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I'm not sure with the state of the internal pullup. If I remember correctly I have no control over pullups when I configure GPIO pins as UART pins.

Comment: If the datasheet is too formidable you can measure it. Put a 10K resistor to MCU ground from the input and see what you measure in volts across the resistor.

Comment: "RX mcu pin that connects to the RX data OUT from RS485 IC" Are you sure you're connecting it right? The TX pin of one device should reach the RX pin of the other, and the same in the other direction. TX->RX. That was my question earlier: Have you connected RX->RX through the divider? I'm even more confused since you mentioned "RX data OUT". RX is an input.

Comment: @Wojciech I've connected just the way you understand. Tx->RX. I just mentioned as Rx data out just to differentiate it.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany just now checked the voltage of the pin when its floating. It seems I have enabled the pullups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost definitely you've got the pullup enabled. Here's a [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tms320f28030.pdf) extract from a Picolo controller. The SCI may take over the in/out definitions, but the pullups can even be enabled on pins defined as outputs, and there is certainly no good reason to prevent the pullup from being enabled on an SCI RXD input.

[image]

Comment: thanks for pointing it out. I think I got confused with the pullup part.